# Jquery: Get attribute value of dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a div dynamically, and on click event I want to get it's attribute value, but when I try to do that, it throws me an error. "`jQuery(...).attr(...).val is not a function`", refer my code below

```
    jQuery("#target1").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("#target_block").append('`<div id="target2" data-rel-pid="12345">Click Me</div>`');
    });

    jQuery("#target2").on("click", function(){
        var bid=jQuery(this).attr("data-rel-pid").val();
    });
```

Comment: Remove `.val()` from that line.

Comment: Is `handler` being invoked, I suspect it will not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error is in this line :

```
var bid=jQuery(this).attr("data-rel-pid").val();
```

There is no need to cal .val() on .attr()

```
var bid=jQuery(this).attr("data-rel-pid");
```

.attr() itself will return the value.

For more to this, refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .val()

```
jQuery("#target2").on("click", function(){
var bid=jQuery(this).attr("data-rel-pid");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using jQuery and you want to fetch a data attribute you can also do something like this.

```
$("#target2").on("click", function(){
 var bid=$(this).data("rel-pid");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As `target2` is being appended later in the life cycle of the web page, you need to use `event delegation` to attach event to dynamically appended elements.

Remove `.val()`, Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

Try this:

```js
jQuery("#target1").on("click", function() {
  jQuery("#target_block").append('<div id="target2" data-rel-pid="12345">Click Me</div>');
});

jQuery("#target_block").on("click", '#target2', function() {
  var bid = jQuery(this).attr("data-rel-pid");
  alert(bid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target1">target1</div>
<div id="target_block">target_block</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code -

```
jQuery("#target2").on("click", function(){
    var bid = jQuery(this).data("rel-pid");
});
```